# Windows error 0xc000025 on boot - same error when booting from recovery usb

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bsod

**Summary**

I removed the SSD drive of my computer running Windows 10 in order to plug in another disk and do some maintenance on that disk. I only used a live USB with GParted while the foreign disk was installed. Then I reinstalled my SSD and tried to start Windows again. But I am then met with a blue screen and a windows "0xc000025" error.

**Description**

The text on the blue screen says (roughly translated from Swedish) "Your PC needs to be repaired. An unexpected error occurred. Error code: 0xc000025. You need to use recovery tools.."

I've had this error before so I know that it is likely related to boot data on the drive being in some way corrupted. Last time I solved it by creating a recovery CD and then fixing MBR and BCD.

So I created a windows recovery USB from another computer. But when I try to boot from this USB I get the same error code. Only thing to note is that this message is in English, while the error I get when trying to boot from my SSD is in  Swedish. I also tried creating a bootable USB with Hirens Boot CD, but get the 0xc000025 error code trying to boot from that too.

Both recovery USBs works well on another computer.

I also tried booting from a live USB with GParted that is based on Linux. This boots without problems.

Using a linux-based recovery usb I've checked the status of my SSD. It doesn't report any SMART errors and a surface scan shows no bad sectors.

**Problem**

So the problem I'm facing right now is that it seems I'm not able to boot my computer from any windows-based media and consequently not able to fix the MBR/BCD of my ssd-drive.

What could cause this behaviour and what can I do be able to boot from a windows-based usb??

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Tried removing all hard disk from the computer and tried booting it from an usb. Still got the 0xc000025 error.

That led me to the conclusion that this was not related to the disks of the computer at all. Tried resetting the motherboard/CMOS by removing the battery from it and waiting for 60 minutes.

On next reboot I had to enter basic BIOS settings again (since it reset) but after that it boots again without problems.